# GTK, How to get apps to use a modified libgtk?

Tags: gtk, ld

In `/opt`, I unpacked a GTK tarball, modified a couple `.c` files in minor ways, ran `./configure` (without any options) and `make` (but not make install), then ran one of GTK's tests to confirm my changes were implemented.  They are.

I renamed the linux distribution's `libgtk` in `/usr` to back it up.  In it's place I created a symbolic link to the `libgtk` in `/opt` that has my mods.

I've carried this out for both the 2.0 and 3.0 versions.

Yet apps, Firefox for example, still seem to be using the distribution's default libraries.

What steps am I missing?

Comment: Probably need to run `/sbin/ldconfig`, but I don't know if it will like your symlinks, at least from my reading of the docs.

Comment: @ergosys - thanks, that seems to have been the right track anyway!  i looked again at all the symlinks.  Some were not as I had intended.  I manually remade the cascade of symlinks to be correct, ending with a symlink to the modified `libgtk` in `/opt`.  Success: The apps used the modified version.  Then I ran ldconfig again, which rewrote cascade to use the original (renamed) libgtk.  I've noticed at times that apt-get will run ldconfig.  That must be what messed it up for me.  Guess I need to read up on configuring ldconfig.  No matches are returned by `grep gtk /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*`

Comment: @ergosys: that should have been an answer, not a comment...

Comment: @liberforce, my policy is to answer only when I'm sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll add to *ergosys* comment about running `ldconfig`, that what you may want to do is to add the path to your customized version libraries directory (something like in `/opt/gtk-2.xx-customized/lib` or `/opt/gtk-3.xx-customized/lib` using the right version number) in `/etc/ld.so.conf`. By running `ldconfig` as root afterwards, it should update the linker cache. The path to your customized version needs however to be specified before the one to the system's. That way the change is system wide, and you don't mess with the files created by you distro, which will please your package manager. Original and customized versions will lie in separate directories, easing the maintenance. Use the `--prefix` option like this: `./configure --prefix /opt/gtk-2.xx-customized` to specify where to install your built software. Remember to previously creating that directory, and giving your user the corresponding rights to write there.

Please read `man ldconfig` for more information.

If you want for some reason to run just once in a while an application using the original set of libraries, just use the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment var to point to the dir you want to inspect before all others already known by `ld`, which would this time be the one where lies your original library. The syntax is `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib" name-of-your-application`. Don't forget that on 64bits systems, the library dir may be named lib64.

Comment: thanks, that works too and is much cleaner than my manual symlinks.  Some details though: if prefix is `$where`, then the corresponding line in `/etc/ld.so.conf` needed to be `$where/lib`, and the one-off command: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$where/lib" name-of-your-application`

Answer (score 0):

i think i have it solved. I had backed up the original libgtk by
dot-appending to its name. For example,

`libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.2400.10`

renamed to

`libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.2400.10.original`

Now, I've changed the dot to a dash: `.original` to `-original` ... and ldconfig seems to now ignore the backup copy, which is good.

The following is robust to ldconfig:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  libgtk-3.so -> libgtk-3.so.0
lrwxrwxrwx  libgtk-3.so.0 -> libgtk-3.so.0.400.2.alt
lrwxrwxrwx  libgtk-3.so.0.400.2 -> libgtk-3.so.0.400.2.alt
-rw-r--r--  libgtk-3.so.0.400.2-original
lrwxrwxrwx  libgtk-3.so.0.400.2.alt -> /opt/gtk/gtk+-3.4.2/gtk/.libs/libgtk-3.so.0.400.2

lrwxrwxrwx  libgtk-x11-2.0.so -> libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
lrwxrwxrwx  libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 -> libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.2400.10.alt
lrwxrwxrwx  libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.2400.10 -> libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.2400.10.alt
-rw-r--r--  libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.2400.10-original
lrwxrwxrwx  libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.2400.10.alt -> /opt/gtk/gtk+-2.24.10/gtk/.libs/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.2400.10
```

Comment: the above approach using manual symlinks does work nicely, but the people who suggested ldconfig were on a better, cleaner, more elegant track, though theirs is more bureaucratic.  anyway, i have converted to their suggestions, thus i clicked the checkmark to accept their answer.  thanks guys!

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. The main problem with using symlinks that way is that updating GTK once your distro releases an update (think bug fixes, security) you will break your changes. The links will be overwritten by the package manager.